how to reduce padding in icon in flutter_quill toolbar
this is my code section where i used toolbar

  SizedBox(
              width: 250,
              child: QuillToolbar.simple(
                configurations: config,
                controller: _controller,
              ),
            ),

my configuration is like this
  final config = const QuillSimpleToolbarConfigurations(
    color: Colors.white,
    multiRowsDisplay: true,
    toolbarSectionSpacing: 0,
    showBoldButton: true,
    showItalicButton: true,
    showStrikeThrough: true,
    showListNumbers: true,
    showListBullets: true,
    showLink: false,
    showUnderLineButton: false,
    showDividers: false,
    showFontFamily: false,
    showFontSize: false,
    showLineHeightButton: false,
    showInlineCode: false,

  );

I want to reduce padding between icon and change selected icon decoration in flutter quill. Any help would be appreciated or is there better option than flutter quill?

What do you mean by this, change selected icon decoration?
